# SMB Signature Verification Return Error= -13

Tags: ubuntu, samba4

Setting up a backup server for the purpose of backing up several other servers in our group. Mounting one of the shares I need to backup causes the server to complain:

fstab entry:

```
//10.0.10.228/Corporate /mnt/server/Corporate cifs nobrl,_netdev,vers=1.0,noserverino,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/administrator/.smbcred   0       0
```

The share is mounted and I can navigate around in the folder; however if I issue :

```
sudo rsync -avz /mnt/server /backup/Monday
```

The server screeen starts filling up with:

```
CIFS VFS: SMB signature verification returned error = -13
```

This is all running on Ubuntu Server 18.04 with Samba AD/DC configured.
I'm not sure what is causing these errors and searches have had me all over the place with different responses.  It appears that the files are being rsync'ed; however I am not certain what is causing this error or how to fix it.

Comment: Am I not giving enough information?

Comment: did you find any solution on that?
I have the same problem, sync works, but syslog is flooded with this error message.

Comment: I couldn't find the cause of the errors so I had to go a different route. Sorry.